# Material ui change color for select box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my code,

```
import { AppBar, createStyles, MenuItem, Select, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { useState } from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
    createStyles({
        selectRoot: {
            color: "white",
        }
    }),
);

const Navbar = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [sort, setSort] = useState(1);

    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ flexGrow: 1}}>Tools</Typography>
                <Select
                    variant="standard"
                    value={sort}
                    className={classes.selectRoot}
                    onChange={(event) => setSort(event.target.value)}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={1}>Default sort</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={2}>Sort by Title ASC</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={3}>Sort by Title DESC</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

What I need to change the color of select tag. In inspect seems like overridden by this class.

```
.css-a88p61-MuiInputBase-root-MuiInput-root{
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}
```

Comment: backgroundColor or borderColor which color do you want to change

Comment: @SachinYadav font color

Comment: Font color of menuItem ?

Comment: @SachinYadav No for "select".

Comment: Please be clear how are you going to set font color of select if there is no font in it, it has to be for menuItems or you need to change menuItems background color when select dropdown is selected

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .MuiMenuItem-root inside your select tag , this will color your entire menuItems.

```
 MenuProps={{
                        sx: {
                          "&& .MuiMenuItem-root":{
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            color: "orange"
                          }
                        }
                       
                      }}
```

But if you don't want to apply color to a specific menuItem then you need to use the `.MuiMenuItem-gutters` class in Select Component and set `disableGutters={true}` to the menuItem to which you don't want to apply the color

> Example using `.MuiMenuItem-root` class

```
import { AppBar, createStyles, MenuItem, Select, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { useState } from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
    createStyles({
        selectRoot: {
            color: "white",
        },
        menuItem:{
            color: "red",
        }
    }),
);

const Select = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [sort, setSort] = useState(1);

    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ flexGrow: 1}}>Tools</Typography>
                <Select
                    variant="standard"
                    value={sort}
                    className={classes.selectRoot}
                    onChange={(event) => setSort(event.target.value)}
                    MenuProps={{
                        sx: {
                          "&& .MuiMenuItem-root":{
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            color: "orange"
                          }
                        }
                       
                      }}
                >
                    <MenuItem  value={1}>Default sort</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem  value={2}>Sort by Title ASC</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem  value={3}>Sort by Title DESC</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Select;
```

> Example using `.MuiMenuItem-gutters` class

```
import { AppBar, createStyles, MenuItem, Select, Toolbar, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import { useState } from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
    createStyles({
        selectRoot: {
            color: "white",
        },
    }),
);

const Select = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [sort, setSort] = useState(1);

    return (
        <AppBar position="static">
            <Toolbar>
                <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ flexGrow: 1}}>Tools</Typography>
                <Select
                    variant="standard"
                    value={sort}
                    className={classes.selectRoot}
                    onChange={(event) => setSort(event.target.value)}
                    MenuProps={{
                        sx: {
                            "&& .MuiMenuItem-gutters": {
                                backgroundColor: "pink",
                                color: "red"
                              },
                        }
                       
                      }}
                >
                    <MenuItem  disableGutters = {true} value={1}>Default sort</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem  value={2}>Sort by Title ASC</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem  value={3}>Sort by Title DESC</MenuItem>
                </Select>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    )
}

export default Select;
```

Refer [documentation](https://mui.com/api/menu-item/#css) for more css properties

Comment: No I wanted to change the color in select tag.  :(

Comment: What does the `&&` do? I haven't seen this before but it works